# Creating non-framework classes in CakePHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, cakephp

I'm making a tournament manager in CakePHP 1.3 and I have a tournament controller which is fine but I want to implement a interface that can be used to define how a tournament runs.

the controller needs to load a concrete class that implements the `TournamentStyle` interface that defines how the tournament works. At the end of a round the `TournamentStyle` is used to calculate the scores and winners and generate the next round of matches.

That gives me a .php file for the interface and other files for the various styles. My question is: where would I put these files and how would I load them into my tournament controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw the interface into app/vendors and use [App::import()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/538/Loading-Vendor-Files) to load it.

Comment: Can you load a directory using import?

Comment: No but you can load the files in the directory.  require() and include() are also incapable of loading a directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would put those files in either `app/libs` or `app/vendors` depending on where you feel like putting them.  Both libs and vendors can have files loaded with `App::import()`.  You could also use plain old include.